# How to store objects with different datatypes in one vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm completely confused with the way I can store objects with different datatypes in one vector.
E.g I have Class1 with some specified data and Class2 with another one. I need to place them into vector in the order they are created. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: A vector can only store elements of a single type. If you have classes inheriting from the same base class you can store pointers to the base class but I think this is not what you try to do

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev yeap, that's why I'm confused

Comment: Look at `boost::variant`.

Comment: Create a `structure` and store pointer of both `class1` and `class2` in this `structure` and then make a `vector` of that structure .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few alternatives.

If the different data types you want to store are POD types, you can create a union to store them.

```
union u {
    int intvalue;
    double double value;
}

vector<u> vec;
```

You can also store pointers to instances of disparate types via a union.

A disadvantage of using unions like this is that you need some way of knowing what type is a actually stored in each instance.

Or If you want to store objects, you can arrange your objects to all inherit from a common base class, then allocate instances of your class on the heap and store pointers to the instances in the vector. Depending on how your objects are too be used you would have to cast the pointers and/or use virtual methods to call methods on the objects.

```
class base {
...
}

class d1 : base {
...
}

vector<base*> vec;

vec.push_back((base*)new d1());
```

Or you can use [boost.variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html). This is arguably the best way because it is typesafe compared to the other methods I mentioned.